Action after one hour from the specified time
I have a service that records users of my telegram bot in the database. And I need to implement a mechanism by which if a user has not responded for an hour, he is recorded in the database. The user has a field with the time of the last activity.
public class DataBaseListener {
    private final UserStateManager userStateManager;
    private final QuestionService questionService;
    private final UserStateService userStateService;

    /**
     * <p>С определенной в application.properties задержкой запускает запись всех пользователей, не допрошедших опрос, в базу данных</p>*/
    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${scheduler.save-inactive-person.interval}", initialDelayString = "${scheduler.delay-before-first-call.interval}")
    private void pullUsersToDB(){
        userStateService.saveUsers(usersNeededWriteToDb());
    }

    /**
     * <p>Возвращает лист всех юзеров, которые полностью прошли опрос либо не отвечали больше часа</p>*/
    private List<UserState> usersNeededWriteToDb(){
        if (userStateManager.getUserStates().isEmpty()){
            log.info("Список пользователей пуст! Нечего проверять и записывать в бд");
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }

        return userStateManager.getUserStates()
                .values()
                .stream()
                .filter(x-> x.getLastActivityTime().isBefore(LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(1)))
                .toList();

    }
}


`
I tried to use scheduler, but I could only achieve checking every hour for each user. This raises the problem that the user can be inactive for more than an hour, and I don't know how to solve this. I was advised to use SchedulerService, but I didn't figure out how to use it to achieve the goal.

Are you using some framework like Spring or Jakarta EE? And explain/link “SchedulerService” as that is not a class bundled with Java.


Can you rely on your JVM being up all day ever day?  If so, then you could use a DelayQueue which holds some data hidden in the JVM until the individual item's delay expires.  You would have 1 thread that uses the DelayQueue.take() method that waits until an expired element is available, it could then persist to the database, it then attempts another take(), in an infinite loop.

if you cannot rely on your JVM being that resilient, then you need a resilient store.  It could be your database.  So you'd have a different table/collection that the user object is stored with the last activity field.  (You should provide a index on that field for efficiency.)  Then you set up a schedule to poll the database as frequently as you like (for example) 10 seconds and look for any user with an activity > 1 hour ago, retrieve these records and process them.  In this approach, there is a "delay" between 0-10 seconds when before the proper "recording" happens.  You can shorten the delay and poll the database more frequently, of course.


